# disable gzip compression in railo

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I want to use cfflush in a backend on some pages. But on railo, the server administrator is configured to use gzip compression. So, the cflush command doesn't work (may be it was a bug, becouse it was reported as a bug, it may not send gzip compression in headers under cfflush, but the bug is marked as resolved, but continue doing the same behavior).
I dont want to disable the gzip compression on all the frontend, only in a few pages in the backend.
There is some way to disable it using a tag on-the-fly as the same way that requesttimeout or the pageencoding?

Comment: Are you using Railo's built in web server? I know IIS will compress content and that keeps `cfflush` from working

Comment: No, i'm using Apache. If i disabled the gzip compression on the server administrator, cfflush works fine. It is not an issue of the webserver, it is caused by the gzip conmpression.

Comment: What bug? What version are you on?

Comment: I am onRailo 4.1.1.009 final, this bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2141

Comment: Question also posted to Railo mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/EfCtqqSpw20

Comment: They have fixed the bug, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2752

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be the way to go, you should just let apache do it since it is more configurable. For example:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

(from http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html)

You can then look at more of the configuration options available to see if you could choose which specific url's you want to enable/disable compression for. 
http://www.schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/config.htm